# Will the upcoming "Gnomebuntu" be an official variant?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I have heard some things about [Gnomebuntu](http://gnomebuntu.org/) which is to be a new Ubuntu variant, although that may not be its final name. There is an article at [world of gnome](http://worldofgnome.org/gnomebuntu-is-set-to-arrive-in-october-18/), which describes it as a community developed variant (much like Xubuntu), but will it be classed as an official variant like Xubuntu? I wonder if anyone else had any more information on the project?

Thanks izx, we might as well leave the question open so people can add more information as the project develops.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- The upcoming 12.10 release of "Gnomebuntu" will NOT be official, only a "community release".
- But according to "Gnomebuntu's" lead packager/developer Jeremy Bicha, [the goal is to eventually "be an official recognized flavor."](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12211923&postcount=94)

  - No timeline is given, but we can hope this will happen by Ubuntu 13.04!
- In the meanwhile, the "official" source for all things "Gnomebuntu" is [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999827).

---

As of 13.04 Ubuntu Gnome Remix is now an official Ubuntu derivative under the name "[Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/)".